How can I share Jupyter kernel along with Linter and Intellisense across multiple notebooks in VSCode
Intro

Sharing the same Jupyter kernel across notebooks is possible and useful in VSCode. When your notebooks grow very long, it becomes impossible to do analysis on the go - It is difficult to find the code I need from a week ago on the one hand, and impractical to reload huge datasets on the other.
However, it is perfectly possible to split your notebooks inside a single folder and connect them all to the same kernel, for example, like so:

Imports Notebook
Load Data Notebook
Single or Multiple Feature Notebooks
Single or Multiple ML Notebooks


Unfortunately, none of the linter/intellisense functionality carries over naturally, as is, in VSCode (and probably using other platforms).

Question
Is there a way to tell VSCode/kernel/interpreter/linter, or something else, to treat all notebook files in a folder as if they were written contiguously into 1 file for this to work?
Any other ideas on how to make it possible to share linting/intellisense in such a way?

It does sound like a good idea, and it might be embraced by some users. However, the vscode-jupyter extension does not currently provide support for this. You can make a feature request and call for votes in the vscode-jupyter repository.
